# deleting one value from a column which is present in the multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which has a column , lets say channel id having value like - AB, ABC, ABCD, ABDHC.. Now i have a requirement to delete channel id - AB

how to achieve it?

Comment: I think you just need to write simple query : delete from your table where requestid ='AB'

Comment: but if you want to delete AB from ABC and set it to c its different

Comment: Are you deleting the entire record/row, or updating the row to remove the "AB" value?

Answer (score 0):

So here is a query that would do it (TSQL):

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
SET [channel id] = SUBSTRING([channel id], 0, CHARINDEX('AB', [channel id]))
+ SUBSTRING([channel id], CHARINDEX('AB', [channel id]) + LEN('AB'), LEN([channel id]))
WHERE [channel id] LIKE '%AB%'
```

This would set any XXXXABYYYY to XXXXYYYY.

Also it would be easier for us to help you if you provided a precise set of what you have and what you want as well as the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the table looks like this?

```
  channel_table:
  ------------
  id |channel_id|  
  ------------
  1  |AB, ABC, ABCD, ABDHC|
  2  |XYZ, ZY|
```

If you have saved values as CSV in a SQL table, then I would prefer to do the math in client side language which is fetching this data. I mean, first detect all the rows which has "AB" like this:

```
select id,channel_id from channel_table where channel_id like '%AB%';
```

The above query would return all the channel_id's which have a regex like *AB*. Now store all these into an array, loop over each of them, break the string with a comma and if you find exact "AB" then remove it from the array. Note that you have to even maintain an "id" column so that you can update the table.

Now after this process, you might have the arrays as:

id array -> 1

channel_id array -> ABC, ABCD,ABDHC

Now update all the id's with the values using an update query in a loop:

```
 update channel_table set channel_id=<modified_channel_value> where id=<saved_id>
```

For a better DB design, you can store channel_id's as separate rows since RDBMS is meant to have a single row for a single value. Storing and processing CSV in a table, Objects in a table will always be difficult.